# работа с массивами, помогите сортировку сделать!

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива, один содержит уникальные значения, а второй много записей с одинаковыми заголовками - наименование услуг и стоимость. Хочу вот сложить все суммы и вывести по позициям за период, чтобы получить результат:

- услуга ________, была оказана ___ раз, на общую сумму ____ р.

Массив с данными, которые нужно посчитать

```
$mv_today[] = array($s_name => array('vol' => $s_vol, 'price' => $u_price));
```

Данные хранятся в виде:

> Мойка кузова включая пороги:1:350/Сухой туман:3:700/

Наименование:категория:стоимость/... Получается я сначала вытаскиваю все из базы, потом на лету формирую отчет за прошедший день/месяц.

Массив с уникальными значениями:

```
$uslugi[] = $s_name;
```

Тут все просто - наименование услуги, больше ничего.

---

Сделать сами массивы у меня кое-как получилось, а вот соединить между собой не получается.

---

```
$result_today = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM history WHERE start_work BETWEEN '$start_date_today' AND '$stop_date_today' ORDER BY  `history`.`start_work` DESC");
while ($row_today = mysql_fetch_array($result_today)){ 
$mv_today_all[] = $row_today[type]; //заносим все значения в массив (грязными)
};//while

foreach ($mv_today_all as $key => $value) {
$str_value = explode("/", $value);
foreach($str_value as $str_val){
list($u_name, $u_cat, $u_price) = explode(":", $str_val);

if ($u_name){
$s_vol = "1";
$s_name = $u_name."#".$u_cat;
$mv_today[] = array($s_name => array('vol' => $s_vol, 'price' => $u_price));
$uslugi[] = $s_name;

}//if ($u_name)
}//foreach($str_value
}//foreach ($mv_today_all

$uslugi = array_unique($uslugi);
```

Comment: покажите сам массив или оба массива, что мы понимали

Comment: Array ( [0] => Мойка кузова включая пороги и продувка#1 [1] => Сухой туман#3 [2] => Абразивная полировка#2 [3] => Жидкое стекло#3 )

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [Мойка кузова включая пороги и продувка#1] => Array ( [vol] => 1 [price] => 350 ) ) [1] => Array ( [Сухой туман#3] => Array ( [vol] => 1 [price] => 700 ) ) [2] => Array ( [Абразивная полировка#2] => Array ( [vol] => 1 [price] => 10000 ) ) [3] => Array ( [Жидкое стекло#3] => Array ( [vol] => 1 [price] => 10000 ) ) [4] => Array ( [Абразивная полировка#2] => Array ( [vol] => 1 [price] => 10000 ) ) [5] => Array ( [Мойка кузова включая пороги и продувка#1] => Array ( [vol] => 1 [price] => 350 ) ) )

Comment: вообще думал делать третий масси, в который после проверки на уникальность записи, если нет - то просто пишем, если есть - добавляем к vol+1 и к сумме сумму

Comment: А, т.е. вы предыдущий вопрос удалили и мой ответ вместе с ним ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mv_today = array($s_name => array('vol' => 12, 'price' => 34));

foreach ($mv_today as $value) {
  echo $value['vol'] * $value['price'];
}
```

Проверка на уникальность, выводит только уникальные значения

```
array_unique($mv_today)
```

Соединить 2 массива

```
array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Фильтрация массива, поиск дубликатов, прибавления по стоимости и общему количеству

```
$mv_today[] = array('Мойка кузова включая пороги и продувка#1' => array('vol' => 1, 'price' => 350)); $mv_today[] = array('Абразивная полировка#2' => array('vol' => 1, 'price' => 10000)); $mv_today[] = array('Сухой туман#3' => array('vol' => 1, 'price' => 700)); 
$mv_today[] = array('Абразивная полировка#2' => array('vol' => 1, 'price' => 10000)); 
$mv_today[] = array('Сухой туман#3' => array('vol' => 1, 'price' => 700));
//print_r($mv_today);
 $tmp = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($mv_today); $i++) { 
  foreach ($mv_today[$i] as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($tmp[$key]))
    {
      $tmp[$key] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
      $tmp[$key]['vol'] = $tmp[$key]['vol'] + $value['vol'];
      $tmp[$key]['price'] = $tmp[$key]['price'] + $value['price'];
    }
  }
}
print_r($tmp);
```

Comment: выводить я уже научился, а вот как скрестить? меня больше интересует проверка на уникальность, замена существующей записи и удаление старой

Comment: я добавил в ответ

Comment: array_unique($mv_today) я думаю не подойдет, ведь он убьет часть строк, которые мне надо посчитать

Comment: он удаляет одинаковые записи

Comment: так в этом и прикол, мы в течении дня предоставляем одни и теже услуги по прайсу, там может быть половина одинаковых

Comment: так что нужно удалить? если не одинаковые тогда, по какому параметру сортировать?

Comment: удалять ничего не нужно, нужно взять массив с наименованием работ, он отсортирован под уникальные значения и как бы запросами вытащить из второго массива значения где название работ совпадает с первым массивом. Т.е. есть услуга "Жидкое стекло", например ее "продали" N кол-ву клиентов, нужно вытащить все значения с заголовком "Жидкое стекло", посчитать кол-во оказанных услуг и общую сумму за период

Comment: можете работающий массив загрузить в вопрос ?

Comment: $mv_today[] = array('Мойка кузова включая пороги и продувка#1' => array('vol' => 1, 'price' => 350));
$mv_today[] = array('Абразивная полировка#2' => array('vol' => 1, 'price' => 10000));
$mv_today[] = array('Сухой туман#3' => array('vol' => 1, 'price' => 700));
$mv_today[] = array('Абразивная полировка#2' => array('vol' => 1, 'price' => 10000));
$mv_today[] = array('Сухой туман#3' => array('vol' => 1, 'price' => 700));

Comment: $uslugi[] = "Мойка кузова включая пороги и продувка#1";
$uslugi[] = "Абразивная полировка#2";
$uslugi[] = "Сухой туман#3";

Comment: $mv_today[] - данные загружаю из базы, они хранятся в строчном виде с разделителями, поэтому подумал что проще будет на массивах, $uslugi[] - перечень услуг (уникальный), нужно каждым значением из $uslugi[], пройтись по $mv_today[], выбрать совпадающие строки, из них забрать все значения и посчитать общее кол-во и общую сумму, например по услуге "Абразивная полировка#2" за прошедший день

Comment: проверьте я добавил код филтрации

Comment: работает немного не так как надо, но направление вы мне задали, тему понял как совместить! Спасибо! Я уже почти доделал и тут новый косяк, после второго цикла частично слетает кодировка, печатает ромбы (( с чего бы это? сижу на денвере, мож кто скажет )

Comment: спасибо, можете отметить мой ответ как правильный, чтоб другие видели тоже?

Comment: я сразу это сделал ;)

Comment: убери и нажмите еще раз не видно, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал вот так, может кому понадобится

```html
$result_today = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM history WHERE start_work BETWEEN '$start_date_today' AND '$stop_date_today' ORDER BY  `history`.`start_work` DESC");
while ($row_today = mysql_fetch_array($result_today)){ 
$str_value = explode("/", $row_today[type]);
foreach($str_value as $str_val){
list($u_name, $u_cat, $u_price) = explode(":", $str_val);

if ($u_name){
$s_name = $u_name."#".$u_cat;

if(!isset($mv_today[$s_name])){
$mv_today[$s_name] =  array('price' => $u_price, 'vol' => 1);
}else{
$u_price = $mv_today[$s_name]['price']+$u_price;
$u_vol = $mv_today[$s_name]['vol']+1;
$mv_today[$s_name] =  array('price' => $u_price, 'vol' => $u_vol);
};//if(!isset($mv_today[$s_name])
};//if ($u_name)
};//foreach
};//while



foreach($mv_today as $key => $today){
print $key." (".$today[vol].") на сумму ".$today[price]."<br>";
}
```